# Наоборот: вводное слово или наречие (нестандартные случаи)

Tags: вводные-слова

**В большинстве случаев различить эти функции несложно:** слово ***наоборот*** является вводным, если  в предложении (данном или с учетом предыдущего текста) **названы обе ситуации**, а ***наоборот*** ― **это такой маркер**, с помощью  которого говорящий обозначает противоположность второго утверждения, например: **Иногда, наоборот, возникает имя, а за ним ничего не стоит.**

Если же вторая ситуация не названа, то она  обозначается необособленным наречием ***наоборот***: **Обычно она всегда хочет сделать как лучше, а получается наоборот.**

Но в некоторых случаях такое простое решение применить не получается, **вот примеры (они разбиты на три похожие группы):**

1)  А в последнее время **наоборот**, только приятные неожиданности.

Время от времени происходит усиление центра, затем **наоборот**― децентрализация.

Препарат не дает никакого преимущества, скорее даже **наоборот** ― снижает общий тонус организма.

**И наоборот**: простейший электрон сам может оказаться вселенной

**Или наоборот** ― с почерком проблем нет, а слова разбирает по слогам, как маленький.

2) **Наоборот** мы теперь сможем конкурировать с ними.

**Наоборот** их в армии стараются не разлучать и в одну часть направляют.

В отличие от рынков Западной Европы и Америки, которые находятся в упадке, наш **наоборот** идёт в гору.

3)  **С однородными сказуемыми**

Он не стеснялся, **наоборот** хвалился, что по дешёвке откупился.

Если кто настаивает проводить скорей ― **наоборот** медленней проводить, отложить.

Почему-то родители на это не так сердились, как на поступки старших дочерей, **наоборот** умилялись.

Вопрос: **Можно ли оставить такую пунктуацию и как она объясняется?**